# How do i set permissions for rating a particular content type?

Tags: drupal, permissions, content-type

I have two content types called 'A' and 'B'.
So lets say Mark creates a content 'A1' using 'A'.
Peter and James are two other fellows who create contents 'B1' AND 'B2' using B.
'B' is node referenced to 'A' and i have used views attach to attach B1 and B2 to A1 by passing node id as arguments.

Now i want Mark to rate(used fivestar module) all the contents referenced to his content(A1) i.e B1 and B2. So Mark should not be able to rate B3 , B4 etc.

Any ideas how can i let someone rate his own contents or contents referenced to his content?

Answer (score 1):

You probably could use Views to show the content that a user should rate , probably using the ID as argument and pulling out the referenced content , then only show fivestar on that specific content.

Comment: sorry dint get you on the last part. how do i show fivestar on that specific content? any settings available for that?

Comment: This should help: http://www.lullabot.com/videos/building-views-fivestar-and-votingapi